# Creating Mongoose/MongoDB constant documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to implement a sort of role-based access control to a NodeJS program I am writting. These roles will be stored with all other data in a MongoDB database, using Mongoose. `RoleSchema` was created for this purpose. Roles have a name of type String, and an array of type String containing the role permisisons. I've posted that code below.

For my API, I have three roles I want to implement, User, Author, and Admin, each with different permissions. What is the best way to create these documents within the collection only once? I understand I can simply create the entries manually, but I feel a programmatic solution would be better. Is it as simple as checking if the roles have been created already, and creating them if they don't, or is there a better way to go about it?

```
const RoleSchema = new Schema({
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: "user",
    },
    permissions: {
        type: [String]
    }
})

const RoleModel = mongoose.model('roles',RoleSchema)
RoleModel.create({
    role: 'user',
    permissions: ['readPost', 'commentPost', 'votePost']
}, (error, result) => {})
```

Answer (score 1):

## Seeding

So, Seeding a database is a process in which an initial set of data is provided to a database.

As a **best practice** instead of manually inserting the data you should configure seed data for automatic insertion of documents.

```
var seeder = require('mongoose-seed');

// Connect to MongoDB via Mongoose
seeder.connect('mongodb://localhost/yourDatabase', function() {

// Load Mongoose models
seeder.loadModels([
    'models/roles.js'
]);

// Clear specified collections
seeder.clearModels(['roles'], function() {

// Callback to populate DB once collections have been cleared
seeder.populateModels(data, function() {
        seeder.disconnect();
     });

  });
});

// Data array containing seed data - documents organized by Model 
var data = [
   {
      'model': 'role',
      'documents': [
          {
              'role': 'user',
              'value': ['readPost', 'commentPost', 'votePost']
          },{
              'role': 'another role',
              'value': ['updatePost', 'deletePost']
          }
       ]
   }
];
```

put that code on a `seed.js` file and run it.

---

[mongoose-seed library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-seed)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the role names are unique, you can indeed query the database and check if a role with the same name already exists. If not, we go ahead and create the role.

This works well for me:

```
const createRole = async ({role, permissions}) => {
    const matches = await RoleModel.find({role}).exec();

    if (matches.length === 0) {
        return RoleModel.create({role, permissions});
    }
};
```

The method can be then invoked in the following way (*given that you've already connected to the database*):

```
const userRole = {
    role: "User",
    permissions: ["readPost", "commentPost", "votePost"]
};

(async () => {
    await createRole(userRole);
    console.log("User role has been created successfully.");
})()
```